# Вызов метода с аргументом типа без явного определения аргумента типа

Tags: c#, методы, generics, типы, аргументы

Есть метод с такой структурой:

```
public async Task<Result<T>> Send<T>() where T : class {}
```

Хотелось бы в некоторых ситуациях вызывать так:

```
Send();
```

При попытке получаю ошибку "Аргументы типа для метода не могут определяться по использованию. Попытайтесь явно определить аргументы типа"
Ошибка мне понятна. Подскажите, есть ли возможность её преодолеть, не определяя явно аргумент типа?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151766/discussion-on-question-by-vladimir--------); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score -2):

Ваш метод

```
public void Send<T>()
{
}
```

Допишите ещё метод

```
public void Send()
{
}
```

И это распространённое явление. Пример:

```
System.Array.Sort(System.Array array);
System.Array.Sort<T>(T[] array);
System.Array.Sort<T0, T1>(T0[] array0, T1[] array1);
```

Всё это можно решить (в некотором смысле) используя "врапперы". "Враппер" в данном случае трактуется - широко. Это обёртка. Это может быть класс оборачивающий класс. Или набор методов оборачивающих методы, и комбинации всего этого.

В вашем случае имеющийся метод можно "обернуть" через другой метод.

```
псевдокод
public async Task<Result<T>> Send<T>() where T : class // метод Send<T>() есть
{
}
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
public async Task<Result<T>> Send() where T : class // допишите нужный Send()
{
    return Send<T>();
}
```

Смысл здесь прост. Вам нужны методы? Так допишите нужные вам методы.

Comment: А как это решить обозначенную автором проблему? И проблема ли это вообще? И метод у автора не `void`.

Comment: Понятия не имею. Если автор спрашивает, то для него (наверное) - это проблема. Как решить - написано. Дописать нужный метод. А если это НЕ авторский код, то весь НЕ авторский код можно обернуть во враппер. И в этом враппере и нашлёпать всяких разных нужных методов автору.

Comment: Без разницы воид у автора или не воид. Пусть что хочет - то и возвращает, что ему нужно. Потому что суть не в этом. Суть в том, что бы автор нужные ему методы написал. Сам. А какие они ему нужны - известно только ему.

Comment: Это не сработает... Т.к. у тебя не в класс передается тип и возвращаемый тобой таск будет зависеть от параметра , а его нет.

Comment: Выше предельно ясно написано - что это всё - псевдокод. И про "врапперы" тоже написано. Это могут быть не только методы, но и классы. То что нужно карячить собственный класс - это весьма очевидно, при условии если это НЕ авторский код. А если это авторский код - то нужно дописать нужный метод в авторский код. И на все "случаи жизни" ответов никогда не будет. Невозможно дать ответы на все случаи. Не известно как там у автора всё устроено в реальном коде.

Comment: "public async Task<Result<T>> Send() where T : class" - не работает: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0080?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0080)

Comment: допишите что бы работало, я вам под вашим дописал, теперь ваша очередь